# Irrelevant/Incorrect person account role is coming up while enabling partner user

Tags: community, partner-communities, community-cloud

I am trying to enable partner user from one contact that is already enabled as partner from one partner account. For the first time, for the first contact I should not have got the roles section while enabling the user, but I'm getting. Moreover, the role that is coming up there is not the correct one. I am not getting the expected roles. Need to know the reason behind this behavior.

For me, I have 2 roles set up in the community settings. Hence, I am expecting to get the below two roles :

- Account Name + partner user
- Account Name + partner Manager

[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem

Comment: I'm having the same problem on a playground after disabling and reenabling the contacts and accounts for partner access. Both measure deemed necessary as the initial setup of the portal user roles was done with german as the default language for the org while my admins language was set to english. when creating the roles the default language caused the roles to be in german which then was not accepted by the trailhead challenge check... so why can't an account be disabled and re-enabled without loosing the proper ways to set up the roles again?

Answer (score 1):

Disable **"Minimize the number of roles created, which improves performance by cutting down processing loads"** under sharing settings in Setup to avoid this issue.

[image]

Similar Discussion can be found in https://salesforceohana.slack.com/archives/C6CGF3QH5/p1653741266115829

Comment: This answer is not helpful! The error described is not related to the number of roles but with a mixup with internal roles.

Comment: The above comment makes sense, as the first contact created on a new account, which is then enabled as a customer user will receive the role as concatenation of the alias of the account owner and a Person Account.

Whenever creating a second contact for that same account, the correct (expected) role will be assigned to the both users (the secondly created user & the first created user with the "wrong" role).

When disabling above setting, the first user will receive the correct role immediately instead of the concatenated "alias_PersonAccount" role.